# How to "talk" with a system process through standard descriptors in Erlang?

Tags: asynchronous, process, erlang, interop

I am writing a tool that is going to call a system process (in this case, Z3 solver) very frequently and I am having troubles setting this up.

What I want to do:

1. Start a `/usr/bin/z3` process with `-in` flag
2. Keep it alive as the process waits for the standard input
3. Send some string to its `stdin`
4. Read a line from its `stdout`
5. Possibly goto 3
6. Kill the process politely

What I tried so far:

- `os:cmd` – this thing doesn't seem to support `stdin`
- Using `port`, but either it doesn't match my usecase or I don't understand it. My attempt:

```
main() ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    Port = open_port({spawn, "z3 -in"}, [{packet, 2}]),
    Port ! {self(), {command, "(check-sat)\n"}},
    receive
        X ->
            X
    end.
```

...but it leaves me waiting infinitely. However for some reason this works with `cat`.

At best I would like to wrap an os process with an Erlang process, but I allow some tradeofs and workarounds. What is the most idiomatic way of doing it?

Comment: Maybe the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33278401/409228) can help?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for